# How to retrieve the sum of items from a sharepoint list

Tags: apache-flex, sharepoint

Is there any way to get the sum of items based on some filters from sharepoint list? I was trying to access the GetListItems method. But this returns all the items in the list. That makes the data heavy. My requirement is to get only the sum of items.

For example items created in a specific year.  I am trying to populate a chart in flex from the sharepoint list. Accessing all the items and then calculating the sum in flex will not work always where the list contains more items.

Comment: Thank you ktharsis. The list which I am accessing contains more thab 16000 items in it. So even if we use view fields, such a huge amount of data cannot be processed.

Comment: If you only return one field the total bytes transferred should be about 100K (large but lots of web pages are more than that). If that is too much, consider writing your own webservice call that sits on the server and returns just the count (it would use the same function but since it runs on the server you don't have to transfer any data over the wire).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `viewFields` parameter of `GetListItems` to only return a single (small) field like ID. It is still data heavy but better than returning all the fields from the list.

There is a `rowLimit` parameter too that you can use to return all the list items instead of only a block at a time.

Info on the GetListItems method with code snippets at MS:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx